# Se puede enviar un form por cada valor de un arrray?

Tags: php

Quiero construir una función en php de forma que envié un formulario por cada uno de los valores de un array.

Seguidamente pongo el código que tengo realizado:

```
   function importar () { 

$productos = ($_SESSION ['CSVpart']);  //El array lo tenemos como variable de sesion.


    foreach ($productos as $valor){
                $csv = $valor; ?>

<div id="enviarFormCsv">

<form method="POST" action ="POST.php" name="enviaCsv" > <input type
="hidden"  name="csv" value="<?php echo $csv ?>"> <input type="submit" value="Confirmar la importación a Prestashop"> </form>

</div> <!--Cierra div EnviaFormCsv.-->

<?php
}   //Cierra foreach. 
}  // Cierra la funcion.
```

Pues con este código se recibe, únicamente, el primer valor del array.

Lo que se necesita es enviar (y recibir) un form por cada valor del array

Comment: Generalmente es lo contrario, los forms existen y desde ellos se envía información, pero aquí, por lo que se ve en el código, lo que quieres ¿es crear varios forms a partir de un array? ¿Es eso lo que quieres? ¿Seguro? ¿O quieres un form que exista y llenar varios inputs de ese form usando el array?

Comment: La información que se quiere enviar desde el form son los valores del array uno a uno, form a form; es decir, se recorre el array, se sacan sus valores y se guardan en $csv y por cada valor del array ($csv) se quiere enviar un formulario con ese valor a la pagina de recepción.

Answer (score 0):

introducir el código aquí

```
<form name="enviandoCsv" method="POST" action ="pagina_recepcion.php"> 
<?php
            $i = 0;
           foreach($productos as $value){ 
?>
            <input type ="text" name="<?='csv' . $i?>" value="<?= $value ?>" hidden>
 <?php
           $i++;
           } //Cierra foreah
?>
            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar Importación">
        </form>

<?php
```

Comment: Creo que el código está claro, pero si alguien necesita explicación no dude en solicitarlo.